# spring data JPA(Hibernate) Projections

Tags: spring-data-jpa, projection

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. In many places in my query, I am using Projections since I don't want all columns to be fetched from DB.

Projections are interface based like :

```
public interface VeryBasicProjection {
    String getTitle();
    String getUrl();
}
```

So my question is whether it actually fetches just two columns or it fetches all columns and then just set these two columns in projections?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data tries it's best to just select those parts that are actually used.

In your case, it actually should just select the two values using a custom SQL statement.

If your interface contains a collection this does not work (without a rather complex query logic), so Spring Data falls back on selecting the complete entity and extracting the values required for the projection. Or at least it will [once this issue is merged](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1173).

You can always verify this behavior by checking the generated SQL in the logs.